# Using hard links to move Windows Users folder

Tags: windows, windows-8, hardlink

I'm currently trying to move bulky folders from my SSD to my HDD (my `Users` folder and `ProgramData` folder). I'm following a [short guide](http://prasys.info/2012/11/move-the-users-directory-from-ssd-to-hdd-in-windows-8/) on using Directory Junctions to do this effectively.
However, this doesn't work for me. This is exactly what I did on my latest attempt:

1. Locate old Users folder on HDD – the one I want to keep
2. Install Windows 8 on SSD
3. Reboot into recovery console – SSD=C: HDD=D:
4. Copy `ProgramData` to HDD `robocopy /copyall /mir /xj C:\ProgramData D:\ProgramData`
5. Reboot into Ubuntu to copy over anything that failed and delete `ProgramData`
6. Reboot into recovery console
7. Rename `C:\Users` to `C:\Users.old`
8. Make junctions

   1. `mklink /J C:\Users D:\Users`
   2. `mklink /J C:\ProgramData D:\ProgramData`
9. Check with `dir` that everything looks okay.

However, when I booted back up, the login splash screen was plain blue, I had no user profile picture, and upon logging in, I get:

> User Profile Service service failed the sign-in. User profile cannot be loaded

So, I moved `ProgramData` back again, and renamed `Users.old` back to Users. This time, the splash screen shows correctly, but I still get the user profile issue.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Please somebody help =[ I just tried again and it failed again! I can't use my PC without doing this and I really don't like the registry hack way

Comment: I've got somewhere! It turns out that because I was using `/xj` in my `robocopy` flags, any required junction points would be missing. In order to make it work, they would have to be manually recreated. Instead, I made an image of my drive and moved it to the HDD - then junctions work. Except for ProgramData... I'm still trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the answer after a lot of playing. The reason this doesn't work is because when copying the data from SSD to HDD, any existing junctions are removed. This is because of the `/xj` flag in `robocopy` which is required to stop it from getting into an infinite loop.

In order to get around this, a PowerShell script *could* be made to do the following:

1. Copy the data from SSD to HDD with `robocopy /copyall /mir /xj C:\Stuff D:\Stuff`
2. For each junction in `C:\Stuff`, create an identical junction in `D:\Stuff`
3. For each junction in `C:\Stuff`, copy the ACL permissions to the corresponding junction in `D:\Stuff`
4. Note the attributes of `C:\Stuff` with `attrib C:\Stuff`
5. Remove or rename `C:\Stuff`
6. Create the junction `mklink /J C:\Stuff D:\Stuff`
7. Apply the attributes of `C:\Stuff` to the junction point with `attrib /L C:\Stuff +H +I` (for example - ProgramData uses these attributes)

Hopefully, this will move everything from `C:\Stuff` to `D:\Stuff` whilst maintaining all junction points, permissions, and attributes.

But there is a 'shortcut', which I took. Instead of bothering with all this, I made a complete [drive image](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_image) of `C:`, and restored it to `D:` (obviously making sure no files were on `D:` that would get overwritten). There is free software out there to do this such as [Macrium Reflect Free](http://www.macrium.com/reflectfree.aspx) and [Drive Image XML](http://www.runtime.org/driveimage-xml.htm).

I then copied any extra data I needed into `D:`, and proceeded to skip to Step 4 of the above. Afterwards, I just removed all of my Windows files that weren't required on the drive (I had to use my Ubuntu USB stick for this part).

All working!